# Load event for iFrame not fired in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, load

Why is the `load` event not fired in IE for iFrames?

Please take a look at [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/GTmKv/7/).

Work perfectly as expected in FF and Chrome, but IE fails.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think for iframes in Internet Explorer you can't set that event handler (onload) programmatically, you need to specify it in your markup.

Something like:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" onload="myFunction();"></iframe>
```

Otherwise IE is just going to ignore the function.

Comment: Btw. the jQuery bound event doesn't work for me in FF too, specifying `onload` works as expected

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work for IE10.  ```onload="alert('moo');"``` does not alert.

Answer (score 3):

IE might have already loaded the content (and fired the event) before you add the handler. I found that when I statically specified the iframe src attr, and added $(x).load event handlers via jquery, firefox (3.6.28) triggered my handlers but IE (8.0.6001.18702) didn't.

I ended up adjusting my test program so that it set the iframe src via javascript after adding the $(x).load handler. My $(x).load handler was called at the same points in IE and Firefox (but note a handler added via iframe onload attribute behaved differently between IE and FF) . Here is what I ended up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">

function show_body(name, $iframe) {
  $('.log').append(name+': '+$iframe.contents().find('body').html()+'<br/>');
}

function actuallyLoaded(name, x) {
  $('.log').append(name+' actually loaded<br/>');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.i1').load(function(){show_body('i1', $('.i1'));});
  $('.i1').attr('src', 'eb_mce_iframe_content.html');
  var $x=$('.i1').clone().removeClass('i1');
  $('body').append($x);
  $x.load(function(){show_body('x', $x);});
  $x.attr('src', 'eb_mce_iframe_content.html');
});

</script>

</head>
<body>

<iframe class="i1" onload="actuallyLoaded($(this).attr('class')+'/'+$(this).attr('src'), this);">
</iframe>

<div class="log">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

... and here was the Firefox "log":

i1/eb_mce_iframe_content.html actually loaded
i1:

Fred the fox.

/eb_mce_iframe_content.html actually loaded
x:

Fred the fox.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning the handler directly to `onload` works in Chrome, FF, and IE (tested with IE 8).

```
(function (selector) {
    var frame = $(selector).get(0);

    if (frame) {
        frame.onload = function () {
            alert('frame loaded.');
        };
    }
})('#myframe');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the JavaScript code with jQuery from [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fit-iframe-to-content/) works if you change the `if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera) {` line to `if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera || $.browser.msie) {`.  So you have the following:

```
$(function(){

    var iFrames = $('iframe');

    function iResize() {

        for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
          iFrames[i].style.height = iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';}
        }

        if ($.browser.safari || $.browser.opera || $.browser.msie) { 

           iFrames.load(function(){
               setTimeout(iResize, 0);
           });

           for (var i = 0, j = iFrames.length; i < j; i++) {
                var iSource = iFrames[i].src;
                iFrames[i].src = '';
                iFrames[i].src = iSource;
           }

        } else {
           iFrames.load(function() { 
               this.style.height = this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
           });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Works for me on >= IE7 and Chrome. I did not check other browsers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I uses `readystatechange` event for IE.

```
var $iframe = $("<iframe>");
$iframe.on("load readystatechange", callback);
```

Comment: Works on ie 11!

Answer (score 0):

Add the prefix "iframe" in front of your id:

```
$('iframe#myFrame').load(function() {
  ...
});
```

Alternativly try to use "ready" instead of "load":

```
$('#myFrame').ready(function()  {
    alert("Loaded");
});
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks, but the 'ready' event is fired before the content of the iFrame is loaded...

Comment: There's no logic to the suggestion that specifying it as an `iframe` in the selector will do anything for it. What's the assumption — that it'll be even more selected? As to how this equates to the `ready` event… The mind boggles.

Comment: The ready event is not valid on iframe documents, see https://dev.jquery.com/ticket/5511

Answer (score 0):

Seis's answer is the correct one, and can be improved to use non-global/anonymous functions.

```
window.dummy_for_ie7 = function() { }
var iframe = $('<iframe onload="dummy_for_ie7" />')[0];
iframe.attachEvent('onload', real_event_handler)
```

To my surprise, this works.

Note: iframe.onload = func() would NOT work, even after that hack. You **MUST** use attachEvent. Go figure.

Note: naturally, this code *verbatim* will not work in standard-compliant UAs.