# iframe onload is not firing

Tags: jquery, iframe, microsoft-edge

i am  using iframe with jquery, like below. Problem is load event is not firing up on microsoft edge browser. I can run the below code with all other browsers. Is there any way or work around to do this?

```
 $('#reportIframe').on('load', function () {
    alert('iframe loaded sucessfully');
});
```

Comment: Is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the parent window?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load event for iFrame not fired in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334520/load-event-for-iframe-not-fired-in-ie)

Comment: dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334520/load-event-for-iframe-not-fired-in-ie

Comment: @Alex what are the odds that 2 Alex post the exact same thread in the exact same second? :D

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36155560/3894981

Answer (score 1):

If iframe `load` event already fired before binding event (maybe because of cache behaviour) and iframe is on same domain, you could try:

```
$('#reportIframe').one('load', function () {
    console.log('iframe loaded');
}).each(function () {
    if (this.contentDocument.readyState === "complete") $(this).trigger('load');
});
```

Comment: Can you answer this question: `Is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the parent window?` ???

Comment: I can confirm that `readyState` will be always `complete` in Chrome 49, even if the iframe is not loaded completely. So this seems to be not a solution.